# 18.04 upgrade dbus fail starting X server

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, xserver, dbus

I upgraded my desktop from 16.04.5 to 18.04.1 and find after booting that the start up freezes. In recovery, looking at the `journalctl` output I see

```
stan-desktop dbus-daemon[3424]: [session uid=0 pid=3422] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
stan-desktop gnome-session[3384]: gnome-session-binary[3384]: ERROR: Failed to connect to system bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Looking at `Xorg.log` there is

```
dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
```

And indeed there is no `/run/dbus` directory and I checked the links here are OK.

I had problems with `cgmanager` on previous attempts and purged it, and upstart and `libcgmanager`, and hopefully configured and installed again but it still persists in one instance. Maybe this is still the problem.

Thanks for any help

Comment: welcome to askubuntu, I made some formatting changes to your post. For a guide on how to format text on this site take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)